# Why no definite article at the start of "Seating capacity in the cinema is for approximately 1,400 people."?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> Seating capacity in the cinema is for approximately 1,400 people. The interior of the theater was remodeled during the period of the late 1940s to early 1950s. ([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Theater,_Westwood_Village))

Why 'the' is not used in first sentence, while it is used in the second?

Comment: it's still unclear... where do you see the 'seating capacity' getting repeated?

Comment: Why there is an article before interior, but none before seating capacity.

Comment: I've seen articles getting dropped *in the beginning of the sentence* especially in news. Call it a style, maybe?

Comment: I have looked at the article and conclude that the way it is written IS idiomatic. It is not simply a headline abbreviation. As a native speaker it does seem reasonable to elide the article here, but not before interior. I find it difficult to rationalise why that is the case. I think it may be because *capacity* is not a count noun. This could be an interesting question to take to ELU. I would suggest you try posting it there. If you would like me to do so, please confirm.

Comment: It is a very interesting and pertinent question which you raise +1.

Comment: Perhaps because the relevance is not shown when talking about the cinema, but when you talk about its interior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we have an abstract or generic noun:

music *instruction*

seating *capacity*

singing *lessons*

and we're not speaking of an instance of such, as in "*the* singing lessons she gives on M-W-F afternoons versus those she gives on T-Th", there is no call for a determiner; it is sufficient to identify the noun with a modifier that provides its type or class:

*music* instruction

*seating* capacity

*singing* lessons

In effect, the modifier is acting as a determiner.

We determine an abstract or generic noun by identifying a type of it.  We determine a concrete noun by indicating whether we mean any noun of its type (a dog) or a particular instance (the dog) or one that is near at hand (this dog) or farther away (that dog) or some subset of its class (few dogs).